# How can I achieve a hover effect like so?

Tags: css, hover

I'm currently trying to achieve a hover effect like this for my navigation, but failing miserably:

[image: Hover effect image]

I can't seem to find any tutorials relative to what I'm after. Could someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Exactly what effect do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this ([**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/xodalija/1/)) is what you want.

If I understood your problem correctly, the bit that is tricky is that when hover, the orange background extends beyond the parent's height.

I quickly put that example together, and I have the feeling that you can accomplish that entirely with a `:before` element.

HTML:
    
      Climate
      Contact Us

CSS:

```
html {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgb(29, 106, 173);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  font-size: .9em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 80px 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: rgb(29, 106, 173);
  background-color: rgb(240, 139, 0);
}

nav a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(240, 139, 0);
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

nav a:first-of-type {
  order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

terribly vague question. check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

for this specific question, you can use CSS. lets say you have a class for your menu items called `.menu-item`

you can write

```
.menu-item:hover{
    background:#ccccccc;
}
```

where `cccccc` is whatever colour you want.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ([**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JjzBn/1/)).

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Hover">Hover me!</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Hover {
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}

#Hover:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```